# Getting list of available network interfaces in Android

Tags: android, android-networking, network-interface

This is a follow up question to this question:

[How to determine which network interface is for Wifi, 3G, 4G (LTE) & VPN in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24647320/how-to-determine-which-network-interface-is-for-wifi-3g-4g-lte-vpn-in-andr)

I got the network interfaces and their names and I need to display a list with their type (VPN, Wifi, 3G, 4G, Local etc.).

How can I know the type of each by the interface's name? ("local", "eth0" and so on..). I need the list of display names with which I can identify each type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android NetworkInterface. What are the meanings of names of NetworkInterface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33747787/android-networkinterface-what-are-the-meanings-of-names-of-networkinterface)